# Parallelisation of a Sequential Program (maze)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, task, java.util.concurrent

In the university we have a project in which we have to parallelise a sequential search from start to exit in a labyrinth.
My approach is based on ForkJoinTasks. 
A "Start" task is triggered and executes the search algorithm from the starting point to the first branching point. For each further potential path that can be taken at the branching point (2 or 3), a new SubTask with the same search algorithm is executed (recursively), whereby the path taken so far up to this branching point as well as the first point of the potential further path after this branching point is to be passed as starting point. 
This runs until a task has found the exit, then the total path from start to exit is returned. Other tasks which at some point do not get further will then return null. 
The parent task compares the results recursively and finally the path is returned.

This approach works up to a size ~500X500, for sizes beyond that it doesn't work or is slower than the sequential approach. I suspect that the task generation is too large for each further path at a branching point in such large labyrinths and the system is overloaded. So it seems that the program cannot be parallelized in this way, because it must work at least for labyrinths with the size 1000X1000. 
Do you have any ideas what can be parallelized instead of searching on every further way? I don't want to have a solution, I just need alternatives what can be done instead.

Thanks in advance!!!

thats what i did already, it worked for "small" labyrinths:

```
    @Override
    public Point[] compute() {
        Point current = p;

        ArrayDeque<Point> resQ = null;

        Point[] finalPath = getTaskQ().clone();
        List<Point> l = Arrays.asList(finalPath);
        ArrayDeque<Point> pathSoFar = new ArrayDeque<Point>(l);

        while (!labyrinth.isDestination(current)) {

          visit(current); //turns into true in list with false boolean for every point


          Direction[] dirs = Direction.values();
          int dirsCount = 0;
          HashMap<Integer, Point> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();


          for (Direction directionToNeighbor : dirs) {
            Point neighbor = current.getNeighbor(directionToNeighbor);
            if (labyrinth.hasPassage(current, directionToNeighbor)
                    && !visitedBefore(neighbor)
                    && (!labyrinth.isBlindAlley(neighbor, 
          directionToNeighbor.opposite)
                    || labyrinth.isDestination(neighbor))) {
                ++dirsCount;
                hmap.put(dirsCount, neighbor);
            }
            }  if (dirsCount == 3) {

            pathSoFar.add(current);

            ParallelMazeSolver newDirectionTask1 = new 
            ParallelMazeSolver(hmap.get(1), i, pathSoFar.toArray(new 
            Point[0]));

            ParallelMazeSolver newDirectionTask2 = new 
            ParallelMazeSolver(hmap.get(2), i, pathSoFar.toArray(new 
            Point[0]));

            ParallelMazeSolver newDirectionTask3 = new 
            ParallelMazeSolver(hmap.get(3), i, pathSoFar.toArray(new 
            Point[0]));
            invokeAll(newDirectionTask1, newDirectionTask2, 
            newDirectionTask3);
            try {
                return 
                    (compare(newDirectionTask1.get(),newDirectionTask2.get(),
                     newDirectionTask3.get()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
            if (dirsCount == 2) {

            pathSoFar.add(current);

            ParallelMazeSolver newDirectionTask1 = new 
            ParallelMazeSolver(hmap.get(1), i, pathSoFar.toArray(new 
            Point[0]));

            ParallelMazeSolver newDirectionTask2 = new 
            ParallelMazeSolver(hmap.get(2), i, pathSoFar.toArray(new 
            Point[0]));

            invokeAll(newDirectionTask1, newDirectionTask2);
            try {
                return 
            (compare(newDirectionTask1.get(),newDirectionTask2.get()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }

            }
            else if (dirsCount == 1) {

            if(pathSoFar.peekLast() != current)
                pathSoFar.add(current);
            current = hmap.get(1);
            hmap.clear();

            } else if (dirsCount == 0) {
            return null;

            }

        }


        if(pathSoFar.peekLast() != current)
        pathSoFar.addLast(current);

        return pathSoFar.toArray(new Point[0]);
       }
      }
```

Comment: Please provide minimum working code that we can 'fix'. Read the Tour in the help center for guidelines.

Comment: Speed doesn't improve after you've saturated your CPU cores with the maximum amount of work (#hyperthreading plus some extra to 'fill in gaps'). If your quad-core CPU has 8 threads, try with a pool of 16 threads. Use a bounded thread pool with a queue, for example `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16)`. You can add jobs ad infinitum but only 16 ever run. When jobs finish (find dead end or exit) other jobs in the queue get to run. Disclaimer: your case probably has a more elegant solution than this, because once you find the exit other jobs don't need to run.

Comment: now there is the whole compute method in the post

Comment: That sounds like a fun and interesting problem that you can learn a lot from. If the task generation is too large, could you decrease the task generation?